# How to set session when using connect-redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to set session when using `connect-redis`?

```
app.use(require('express-session')({    
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'lalala',
}));`

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('session: ', req.session);        
});
```

I can get

```
session:  Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

But if use connect-redis:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'lalala',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379}),
}));
```

the code print `undefined`.

Comment: Start by logging errors by setting the [`logErrors`](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#options) option to `true`. It may be that `connect-redis` can't connect to Redis.